# Tem como escolher a moeda que o numral.js vai formatar por paramentro

Tags: javascript, typescript, numeraljs

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de escolher a moeda em que o numeral vai formatar, passando ela por parâmetro, eu nao gostaria de usar o locale, pq em algumas situações nao vai funcionar, estou usando assim pra formatar agr:

```
this.valueFormatted = numeral(value).format("$0,0.00")
```

dessa forma me retorna o valor em R$, mas eu gostaria de por exemplo passar como parametro um US$, e assim me retornar ja formatado nessa moeda

Comment: Veja como [criar uma localização](http://numeraljs.com/#locales) com *numeraljs* e veja também [esse exemplo](https://ideone.com/XLfEhA) usando os objetos nativos.

Answer (score 1):

O valor por defeito é em US$. Se não quiseres usar o locale "pt-br" tens que adicionar o símbolo separadamente.

```
var us = numeral(1000).format("$0,0.00")
console.log(us)
var br = "R" + numeral(1000).format("$0,0.00")
console.log(br);
```